# How to convert object array to comma separated string?

Tags: javascript

Im trying to convert at object array with jQuery or javascript to a comma separated string, and no matter what I try I can´t get it right.

I have this from a select value.

```
ort = $('#ort').val();
ort=JSON.stringify(ort)

ort=["Varberg","Halmstad","Falkenberg"]
```

How can I convert it to a string looking like this?

```
ort=Varberg,Halmstad,Falkenberg
```

Any input appreciated, thanks.

Comment: use [`join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) in example `["i", "am", "too", "lazy", "to", "search"].join();` will output `"i,am,too,lazy,to,search"`

Comment: you don't even need to explicitely `join()` you can simply convert it to a String. Like `""+["Varberg","Halmstad","Falkenberg"]` or `String(["Varberg","Halmstad","Falkenberg"])` or `["Varberg","Halmstad","Falkenberg"].toString()`

Comment: That's a simple solution:

    let ortObjectToArray = JSON.parse(ort);
    let ortDecode = ortObjectToArray .join(',');

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

```js
let arr = ["Varberg","Halmstad","Falkenberg"]

console.log(arr.join(','))
```

Comment: Thanks, but Im getting an error, TypeError: ort.join is not a function. (In 'ort.join(',')', 'ort.join' is undefined) ?

Comment: you can use `.join()`. Default value for separator is `,`

Comment: @ClaesGustavsson can you tell what console log of `console.log(ort, typeof ort)` shows ? without that it's possible to tell you exact reason.

Comment: @Cid thanks for pointing out mate, but i prefer this for the shake of readability :)

Comment: Code, Im getting ["Varberg","Halmstad","Falkenberg"] string from that.
I tested str = ort=["Varberg","Halmstad","Falkenberg"].toString();
console.log(str); and that givs me Varberg,Falkenberg,Halmstad in safari, but if I try in IE11 then it show ["Varberg","Halmstad","Falkenberg"] in the console?

Comment: @ClaesGustavsson join is an array method. you need to parse string to array first you can use this `JSON.parse(`["Varberg","Halmstad","Falkenberg"]`).join(',')`

Comment: Code, THANKS a lot!! Now I finally get Varberg,Falkenberg,Halmstad in IE11 as well haha.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Array.prototype.join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to to convert it into a comma separated string.

```js
let str = ort=["Varberg","Halmstad","Falkenberg"].join(","); //"," not needed in join
console.log(str);
```

A simple `toString` also works in this case.

```js
let str = ort=["Varberg","Halmstad","Falkenberg"].toString();
console.log(str);
```

Comment: you can use `.join()`. Default value for separator is `,`

Comment: @Cid yes right!

Answer (score 0):

Another way to achieve this is by using `Array.prototype.reduce`:

```js
console.log(["Varberg", "Halmstad", "Falkenberg"].reduce((s, el, idx, arr) => {
  s += el
  if (idx < arr.length - 1) {
    s += ','
  }
  return s;
}, ''));
```